# Plotting vectors and planes in 3D with Mathematica

Tags: plot, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying out the Mathematica software, and playing with representing in 3D some vector projections on a plane.

I got to this point:

[image]

I know... It is not looking that impressive, and would like to ask for help modifying the beveling of the red arrowhead, changing the color of the plane, getting a projected vector that looks more like a shadow, and labelling the vectors on the plot. Or some of it...

Here's the code I've used so far:

```
Show[{Plot3D[{z = 0}, {x, 0, .75}, {y, 0, .75}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0.25, 0.25, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 1}}]], Brown, 
    Arrowheads[0.05], Arrow[Tube[{{0.25, 0.25, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]]}]}]
```

Comment: suggest asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com